# where in Shiva purana, it is mentioned that "Shiva" is formless God, and "Shankara" is the form which dwells in Mount Kailsha

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

Where in scriptures it is mentioned that "Shiva" is formless God, and "Shankara" is the form which dwells in Kailasha ?
Kindly give exact verse number.

Comment: Please don't delete a Qn just because it's a duplicate. You have asked a good Qn and it serves as a link to the other Qn. Thanks.